# The flag 'boot' is not available for loop disk labels

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb

I tried to make a bootable usb key, I followed the instructions in this link : [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)

I run :

```
7z x ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -o/media/user1/OCZ/
```

then :

```
parted /dev/sdb set 1 boot on
```

I got this error:

```
Error: The flag 'boot' is not available for loop disk labels.
```

the output of `fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F6FA152A-2CAD-4D85-A562-2D4A92A4968F

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 944409998 943359375 449.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  944410624 976771071  32360448  15.4G Linux swap




Disk /dev/sdb: 30.1 GiB, 32326631424 bytes, 63137952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the output of **sudo fdisk -l** with the USB plugged in?

Comment: `/dev/sdb` points to the usb  key with this command

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you without more information. You can copy the information from your terminal and paste it in your [Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1005594/edit)

Comment: @stumblebee I edited the question

Comment: There are no partitions on the USB. You need to first format the USB, As [instructed in the documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media) that you are following.

Comment: @stumblebee I tried this command `mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdb
` and then `fdisk -l` but I still got the same output

Comment: Is you extract to the partition? user1 is not normally a name like $USER, unless that is your login name? You have to partition in advance & format as FAT32, I prefer gparted, and I normally add boot flag at that time. Then extract to sda1, if unlabels it may be /media/$USER/UUID. Where UUID is UUID of sdx1 on flash drive, where x may be sdb, or sdf whatever flash drive is seen as.

Comment: As @oldfred mentioned, the easiest way to partition, format and set the boot flag is through graphical parted - **sudo gparted**